# How to implement pagination in PHP MVC?

Tags: php, html, css, pagination

I am stuck with implementing pagination into my PHP MVC application. 
This is what I made to show my products and now i am completely stuck because i don't have idea how to implement pagination into my code.
I hope someone will show me example with my code so I can learn for future;

My Controller->Products.php

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class Products extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!isLoggedIn()){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        $this->productModel = $this->model('Product');
    }

    public function index(){
        $products = $this->productModel->getProducts();

        $data=[
            'products' => $products
        ];

        $this->view('products/index', $data);
    }
}
```

My Model->Product.php

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class Product
{       
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
        # code...
    }

    public function getProducts(){
        $this->db->query('SELECT *,
                        products.id as productId,
                        users.id as userId,
                        products.productCreated as productCreated,
                        users.created_at as userCreated
                        FROM products
                        INNER JOIN users
                        ON products.user_id = users.id
                        ORDER BY products.productCreated DESC
                        ');

        $results = $this->db->resultSet();
        return $results;
    }
}
```

and my view Product->Index.php

```html
<?php require APPROOT . '/views/inc/header.php'; ?>
<style type="text/css">
    #abc {
       line-height: 2px;
    }

    #productName {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    }

    #cardid {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    #buybtn {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
</style>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1> PRODUCTS</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10">

        <?php foreach ($data['products'] as $product) : ?>              

        <div class="card" style="width: 150px; text-align:center;display:inline-block;" id="cardid">
           <h4 class="card-title text-center" id="productName"><?php echo $product->productName; ?></h4>
           <img class="card-img-top" src="img/img_avatar1.png" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
        <div class="card-block">

        <p class="card-text">Some example text some example text. John Doe is an architect and engineer</p>
        <p class="card-text" id="abc" style="color:red">125</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link" id="buybtn">Buy now</a>

  </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 jumbotron">
            Container Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php require APPROOT . '/views/inc/footer.php'; ?>
```

I saw a lot of threads about pagination but I don't have idea how to implement it here so I can show only 10 products per page...

Comment: Usually you might want to have an additional parameter to the view / url for example, `www.example.com/posts/1`  where 1 is the page #. In your php code you can grab this value to add a combination of LIMIT and OFFSET to your query.
i.e.  if the request is for `www.example.com/posts/12`, your query will be `SELECT * from ... LIMIT 10 OFFSET ({12 - 1}* 10)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add filters to `getProducts($args)`. You can filter on product name, price range, etc. But you can also chose to send an `$args['page']` and `$args['items_per_page']`. You can than calculate the SQL offset and limit. Check the types though and provide default values and always protect against XSS attacks with functions like `mysqli::real_escape_string`.

This way you can calculate the SQL LIMIT and OFFSET:

```
$limit = $items_per_page;
$offset = $items_per_page * $page;
```

In your links you can add the parameter:

```
<a href="{YOUR_URL}?page=2&items_per_page=11>Previous Page</a>
<a href="{YOUR_URL}?page=4&items_per_page=11>Next Page</a>
```

You can then retrieve these with $_GET and send these to your `getProducts($args)` method.

Comment: Could you please redit my code with your way so i can get the knowledge how to do it in my application.. i don't clearly understand, i will +vote if you do it and mark as answer. I want this method to prevent xss injections

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
This is my htacces

Comment: @JRMC please man edit my application i don't understand you clearly.

Comment: @NoviKorisnikkk: I don't have the time to write everything, but this link might help you out. Success! https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html